WebSocket connection closing unexpectedly
To get around the POST request timeout errors, I've implemented a websocket variant of my code (below) that would send a task client side and awaits a response from my server side (whether the task has been completed successfully or unsuccessfully)
However, I can't figure out why the Websocket would disconnect upon completing the "run_interaction" method. Note: run_interaction is not breaking as I put a debug statement and got (below) this on the console.
Completed result: {'text_output': 'The payment has been successfully processed, and the goods will be shipped soon.', 'session_id': '1519915-f3e6dc73-73ea-42b5-93a7-d3b395c728e6'}
Current specs:
Client is using Quart
Server is using FastAPI
Server side:
@app.websocket("/new_task")
async def websocket_new_task(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        data = await websocket.receive_json()
        print("Incoming Data", data)
        context = data.get('context', '')
        org_id = data.get('org_id', '')
        url = data.get('url', '')  
        task = data.get("task", '')
        token = data.get('token', '')

        input = InteractionInput(
            url=url,
            user_input=task,
            token=token,
            base_prompt="" 
        )

        result = await run_interaction(input, "generalist_endpoint", context=context, task_description=task)
        print(f"Completed result: {result}")

        task_summary = f"Task created for org {org_id} with context: {context}. Result: {result.get('text_output', 'No output')}"
        await websocket.send_json({"response": 200, "task_summary": task_summary})
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        await websocket.send_json({"response": 500, "error": "Internal server error"})


Client side:
    async def perform_action(self, call_sid, context):
        uri = "wss://localhost:5515/new_task" 
        task = """request
        """

        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            task_details = {
                "task": task,
                "context": context,
                "org_id": "orgid-placeholder", 
                "url": "url-placeholder", 
                "token": "t-placeholder",  
            }

            await websocket.send(json.dumps(task_details))
            print("Task details sent, waiting for response...")

            response = await websocket.recv()
            print("Response received from the server:")
            print(response)

            if (call_sid):
                self.track.create_or_update_track(call_sid, on_hold=False)

            return response


Thanks for your responses and help in advance.

In addition to the link provided above, you might find this answer, this answer, as well as this answer and this answer helpful

Thanks for this, Chris. I actually noticed the root cause of my error: while (true) I am sending a websocket request from my end, it turns out that my chat interface was handled through POST requests (and I noticed that the timeouts would always happen within the 30 second mark). On that note, I changed my implementation and that WebSocket Disconnect issue went away. Thank you for providing the resources.
